# How serial is one vote?

Tags: support, voting

Today, serial voting was reversed, decreasing my reputation by 10. I don't care about that, but I would like to understand how a single vote would be considered as "serial voting".

[Help says](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed):

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them.

[image: Voting corrected]

As you can see, there was no vote since July, 31st.

Comment: Also see [this question on main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362020/255554).

Comment: Just so you don't feel singled out.. I too had voting reversed, probably due to the same user. `:)` It's not always *only* your account.. it's more about the **voter** than those that got the votes.

Comment: @Scott: I think that the description in help is somewhat wrong. It says "many of your posts", but it should be "many posts" instead.

Comment: Agreed, Thomas. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have looked into this.

The serial voting was not a serial vote for your account, or a specific Q or A from you.

Rather, the user whose votes have been retracted, cast over 50 votes in the span of a single second on dozens of different accounts. Your account was one of the lucky ones. Obviously, this triggered the suspicious voting pattern and votes were reversed.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Ok, I got that. But, one thing is still unclear: if there was voting, shouldn't there be a +10 for the voting and a -10 for the reversal?

Comment: Yes, that's quite annoying. The system completely reversed the votes, they don't exist anymore. Which means the Reputation page cannot show a rep change for something that doesn't exist. You actually gained the rep, but the system has no event to attach it to, so no way of showing it. But the reversal change is 'real' so it shows up. Rest assured you did not actually lose any rep.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: I think that the description in help is somewhat wrong. It says "many of your posts", but it should be "many posts" instead. Can you change that as a moderator or is this some network wide text which needs a huger audience and broader discussion for a change?

Comment: Correct. The behaviour of the serial vote sniffer has been recently changed by Stack Exchange The Company. But they haven't yet updated the help docs. Hopefully, this will be updated soon.